# Does AVAudioRecorder able to get the sound frequency from mic

Tags: ios, iphone, audio, audio-recording

i am trying to build an iOS 7 application that detecting the sound/song frequency, For `example: Do, Re, Mi, Fa, So, La, Si is represented to 261.63Hz, 293.67Hz, 329.63Hz ,349.23Hz, 392.00Hz, 440.00Hz......`

I read the `SCListener API`, it can run on `iOS 7` Simulator, got the proper frequency. But it doesn't work on real iPhone, it can't get any power and frequency value like below code:

```
Float32 peak_power = [[SCListener sharedListener] peakPower];
Float32 average_power = [[SCListener sharedListener] averagePower];
Float32 frequency = [[SCListener sharedListener] frequency];
```

Also the [SCListener](https://github.com/stephencelis/sc_listener) API has been deprecated (the official site said).

So. an alternative is `AVAudioRecorder`, it can get peakPower and averagePower, but no frequency value return.
anyone know how to get the frequency value from `AVAudioRecorder` or other `iOS` API